# try to SSH connect Centos VM to Windows VM using public key

Tags: windows-10, ssh, virtual-machine, centos, openssh

I have two VMs , one in Centos and one in Windows,  I should SSH connect from Centos VM to Windows VM.  I have no issue to SSH connect with password.  But I have to definitely use publickey to connect without password.
I have been working on this issue for 7 days , still no success  :(((
My private key in Centos VM  is located in
/Home/qriteria/.ssh/id_rsa

AND My publickey in Windows VM is located in 
/C/Users/qriteria/.ssh/authorized_keys

I have OPENSSH server running on Windows VM,  and have editted /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      /C/Users/qriteria/.ssh/authorized_keys

When I try to SSH connect to the Windows VM, 
I receive

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/qriteria/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "qriteriarserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to qriteriarserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com [13.81.120.221] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to qriteriarserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:22 as 'qriteria'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from qriteriarserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Hz5mcGsckn57uftIf5RkVK5WaHnjN799tplaWYVj+eE
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from qriteriarserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 13.81.120.221
debug1: Host 'qriteriarserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/qriteria/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_rsa (0x5593afe58500)
debug2: key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/qriteria/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: On my Windows side,  OpenSSH SSH Server and Authentication Agent are running.  Should I ssh-add any key to Authentication Agent ?    When I try to do this , I receive the following message                            ssh-add ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: According to the debug output, your client offered `/home/qriteria/.ssh/id_rsa` to the server and the server didn't accept it. There are half a dozen reasons why this could happen. Your best bet would be to find the logs produced by the SSH server process and see if it's logging why it won't accept the key.

Comment: I m following the instruction in the link https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh , and checked already many links such as https://serverfault.com/questions/525045/ssh-connection-asks-for-password-although-key-is-accepted but none of them solved the issue.

Comment: I have generated private and public key in the Centos VM, and saved the publickey in authorized_keys in the server (the Win VM that I want to connect to, where there is a OPENSSH server running), and it does not connect. MOREOVER, I had thought perhaps the format of the publickey is not compatible with the OPENSSH, SO I used PUTTY, imported the privatekey, and exported the resulting publickey into the server. Still it does not work.

Comment: I tried also Putty to connect to the Windows VM,  it again connects with password, however when using the putty-generated private and public keys, it rejects saying that "the server refused our key".  So there is definitely an issue with Windows VM,  and OpenSSH server running on top.  Am I doing something wrong ?